# When do pins on Pinterest have titles?

Tags: pinterest

Below is the screenshot of [my board on Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/Ooker777/thoughful-articles/). I don't understand why some pins (actually, most pins) don't have the title of the article.

[image: screen shot]

Here is my analysis:

- Pin 1 and 2 are the same article, but pin 2 is shared to Pinterest through Pocket app in iPad, while pin 1 is pinned directly on web. Neither pin has the title, so I guess whether it is saved by an app or not is not a factor.
- Pin 2 and 3 are saved through the Pocket app, but only pin 3 has a title. This strengthens the point I made above.
- All three pins are saved from one website, so I guess which site is saved is not a factor.

Comment: I’m not 100%, but I believe those are rich pins.

Comment: They are all coming a site which the only content is deep though articles. I have checked [pin 3](http://nautil.us/issue/30/identity/how-the-western-diet-has-derailed-our-evolution?utm_source=pocket&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=pockethits), but I couldn't see why it is a [rich pin](https://business.pinterest.com/en/rich-pins)

Comment: Do you remember if it was pinning from the whole page, or when clicking when that "Pin it!" icon is over an image?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise the whole page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Alex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/1512/alex) is correct. Certain websites create implement "Rich Pins" that Pinterest uses to title pins.

> The bold text occurs when it's a "rich pin". These are pins that link directly to the original site and the site owner has enabled the rich pin feature that Pinterest offers. You will also notice that the text for rich pins begins with a favicon - Empress Of Dirt - Melissa

[Source](http://www.hometalk.com/3165478/q-pinterest-pins-with-bold-text)

Comment: but since three pins are pinned from one website, I don't think that they are inconsistent in using rich pin

Comment: Well, it's quite possible that the website has a bug driving the inconsistency. Or they haven't implemented rich pins site wide.